# How to get test name and test result during run time in pytest

Tags: pytest

I want to get the test name and test result during runtime.

I have `setup` and `tearDown` methods in my script.  In `setup`, I need to get the test name, and in `tearDown` I need to get the test result and test execution time.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 15):

You can, using a hook.

I have these files in my test directory:

```
./rest/
├── conftest.py
├── __init__.py
└── test_rest_author.py
```

In `test_rest_author.py` I have three functions, `startup`, `teardown` and `test_tc15`, but I only want to show the result and name for `test_tc15`.

Create a `conftest.py` file if you don't have one yet and add this:

```
import pytest
from _pytest.runner import runtestprotocol

def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
    reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
    for report in reports:
        if report.when == 'call':
            print '\n%s --- %s' % (item.name, report.outcome)
    return True
```

The hook `pytest_runtest_protocol` implements the runtest_setup/call/teardown protocol for the given test item, including capturing exceptions and calling reporting hooks.  It is called when any test finishes (like `startup` or `teardown` or your test).

If you run your script you can see the result and name of the test:

```
$ py.test ./rest/test_rest_author.py
====== test session starts ======
/test_rest_author.py::TestREST::test_tc15 PASSED
test_tc15 --- passed
======== 1 passed in 1.47 seconds =======
```

See also the docs on [pytest hooks](https://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#hook-specification-and-validation) and [conftest.py](https://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins)).

Comment: This unfortuantely didn't help me enough.
I have a finalizer to a fixture, and this finalizer may mark the outcome as failed.
But the finalizer is executed before pytest_runtest_protocol

Answer (score 1):

unittest.TestCase.id() this will return the complete Details including class name , method name .
From this we can extract test method name.
Getting the results during  can be achieved by checking if there any exceptions in executing the test.
If the test fails then there wil be an exception if sys.exc_info() returns None then test is pass else test will be fail.

Answer (score 1):

can suggest one more way. Define report attribute for every test in pytest_runtest_makereport, after this use it in any fixture. Test name is also available in any moment by os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')

content of conftest.py

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    report = (yield).get_result()
    if not getattr(item, 'report', None) or not report.passed:
        setattr(item, 'report', report)


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def any_fixture(request):
    print(f"test name in setup {os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')}")
    yield
    print(f"test name in teardown {os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')}")
    print(f"{request.node.report.failed=}")
    print(f"{request.node.report.duration=}")
```

content of any test

```
class TestClass:

    def test_body(self, any_fixture):
        print(f"test name in test body {os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')}")
```

output:

```
test name in setup tests/unknown/test_check.py::TestClass::test_body (setup)
test name in test body tests/unknown/test_check.py::TestClass::test_body (call)
test name in teardown tests/unknown/test_check.py::TestClass::test_body (teardown)
request.node.report.failed=False
request.node.report.duration=0.0006430509999999501
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `pytest_runtest_protocol` as suggested with fixture marker solved my problem. In my case it was enough just to use `reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)` within my pytest html fixture. So to finalize the `item` element contains the information you need.

Many Thanks.