# Wrong object passed to pytest hook

Tags: python, pytest

I just started dealing with pytest hooks and I immediately encountered strange behavior of `pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem)` hook in case of calling pytest from python code. I tried to reproduce code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140467/3124227, but in `pytest_runtest_protocol` `myPlugin` object is passed as first argument and not testitem (see screenshot).
[image]

After that line I get exception because `MyPlugin` object has no `ihook` property.

This problem doesn't appear in case of athoner ways of calling pytest (with hook code in `conftest.py`).

Project has only two files.
test_main.py

```
def test_first():
    assert 2 + 2 == 4


def test_second():
    assert 2 + 2 == 4
```

hooks.py

```
import pytest
from _pytest.runner import runtestprotocol


class MyPlugin(object):
    def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
        reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
        for report in reports:
            if report.when == 'call':
                print '\n%s --- %s' % (item.name, report.outcome)
        return True


def main():
    pytest.main(plugins=[MyPlugin()])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Version of pytest: 3.2.1

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python)

Comment: Well, I don't see any relations with my question...

Comment: What arguments will `pytest_runtest_protocol` get when `MyPlugin().pytest_runtest_protocol(*args)` is called? What should you change in order for it to work?

Comment: Okay, I did not realize that these methods should be static. Everything works fine with `@staticmethod` decorator. Thank you for help.